# Express Generator - TypeError: app.set is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-generator

I first created an API with Node/Express by myself to learn from a 'naive' way to the way most programmer do. It's was working well and I decided to try express-generator.

After setting everything up the app works fine.

I added my bunch of code (mainly in app.js and importing few routes to try), I haven't change anything in the bin/www where express is setup.

But at launch I got this error pointing at this particularly file bin/www :

```
app.set('port', port);
    ^

TypeError: app.set is not a function
```

I don't know why this part of code automatically generated didn't want to work now.

Here the 2 principals files

bin/www : (generated-untouched)

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('API:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

app.js :

```js
// Module dependencies
const express = require('express');
const cluster = require('express-cluster'); // fork the service on different thread
const helmet = require('helmet'); // Secure HTTP header
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); // Help to easily parse the body of req/res
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); // Manage MongoDB request

cluster(function(worker) {
  var app = express();

  // MongoDB config
  const config = require('./misc/config/index'); // Config variable like MongoDB credential
  mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
  mongoose.connect(config.getDBConnectionString()); // Config to cnx to mongodb
  // mongoose.connect(config.getDBConnectionString(), { config: { autoIndex: false } });

  // Middleware
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.use(helmet.frameguard()); // Default Value - Help to secure request by putting some setting in the header
  app.use(cors()); // Handling Cross Origin Ressource Sharing

  // Logfile
  const log = require('./misc/log/log');
  app.use(log);

  // Config Landingpage to /
  app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  // Entry point
  const entryPoint = require('./routes/entryPoint');
  app.get('/', entryPoint.index);
  app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(301, '/');
  })

  // API Key handler
  const auth = require('./misc/auth/auth');
  app.use(auth);

  // List
  const list = require('./routes/list/listRouter'); // Get List endpoints
  // app.use('/api/list', list);

  // Map
  const map = require('./routes/map/mapRouter'); // Get List endpoints
  // app.use('/api/map', map);

  module.exports = app;
}, {count: 2})
```

I export app which include express(). So there is something i'm missing here but I don't see what.

Comment: `cluster()` will be async, so at import time there hasn't anything been exported yet. If you need to run your app on multiple CPU's, it might be worthwhile to take a look at [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).

Comment: Yep I just try to remove cluster() and it works. Thank you for pm2 but I heard that pm2 is consuming a lot of ressources ?

Comment: pm2 might be a bit of a hit-or-miss, some people have lots of issues, most (including myself) don't. You can always remove `./bin/www` from the equation, it doesn't provide _that_ much functionality so you could move it to `app.js` (and keep using `cluster()`).

Comment: It's not a big deal for me right now the cluster(). But I can't find with pm2 how to launch a .env file for exemple to get the API_KEY=XXXXXXXXX

Comment: You can set environment variables on the `pm2` command line: `env API_KEY=XXX pm2 ...`. Or use something like [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) in your app to read a file containing env vars.

Comment: Nice... Put everything in a respond and I upvote and validate your tips ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by this setup:

```
cluster(function(worker) {
  var app = express();
  ...
  module.exports = app;
}, { ... });
```

Because `cluster` will call the "worker function" asynchronously, the export is done asynchronously as well, which is too late for `bin/www`. Aside from that, the worker function will run in a separate process, which also complicates things.

Because `bin/www` is relatively simple in terms of what it does, you could opt for moving its contents (or at least the gist of what it does) to `app.js`, and start your app with `node app.js`. You could even replace `bin/www` with a simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node 

require('../app');
```

Alternatively, you can leave your code as-is and rely on an external program to provide load balancing across the available CPU's. A popular solution for that is [`pm2`](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/), although it doesn't work well for everyone (bit of a hit-and-miss, it seems).

If you need to pass environment variables, you can do so from the command line:

```
$ env API_KEY=XXX pm2 start app.js
```

Or create [a configuration file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/#application-declaration) for your app.

There's also a package called [`dotenv`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) that will allow your Node app to read environment variables from a file directly.